# How to extract chats from API response with Ionic 2 rest API

Tags: ionic2, angular2-services

**I have an http API returning data in this format.**

```js
{  
   "conversations":[  
      [  
         {  
            "_id":"59563b3a5ab1af1f04d0bf52",
            "updatedAt":"2017-06-30T11:51:22.808Z",
            "createdAt":"2017-06-30T11:51:22.808Z",
            "conversationId":"59563b3a5ab1af1f04d0bf51",
            "body":"Hello Tom",
            "author":{  
               "_id":"595603e325a2b014e07c69cf",
               "profile":{  
                  "firstName":"Paul",
                  "lastName":"Obunga"
               }
            },
            "__v":0
         }
      ],
      [  
         {  
            "_id":"5956462c5ab1af1f04d0bf54",
            "updatedAt":"2017-06-30T12:38:04.469Z",
            "createdAt":"2017-06-30T12:38:04.469Z",
            "conversationId":"5956462c5ab1af1f04d0bf53",
            "body":"Hello Tomusange",
            "author":{  
               "_id":"595603e325a2b014e07c69cf",
               "profile":{  
                  "firstName":"Paul",
                  "lastName":"Obunga"
               }
            },
            "__v":0
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Am trying to create a simple http provider in Ionic 2 to return the message body of each conversation and the first and lastname but not really getting through.

Here is my Message Service extract

```js
fetchConversations() {
  return new Promise((reslove, reject) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', '');
    this.http.post('https://localhost:3000/api/chats', {
        headers: headers
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        let data = res.json();
        let conversations = data.conversations;
        

        resolve(conversations);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  })
}
```

Then in my ConversationListPage.

```js
this.restProvider.fetchConversations()
  .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: How can I get the response of each conversation and display an Ionic ion-item for each conversation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of result | async">
    {{item.author.profile.firstname + ' ' + item.author.profile.lastname + ': ' + item.body}}
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Something like this?